# Difference between sparse features

Tags: input, classification, rasa-nlu, rasa

I’m using: `EmbeddingIntentClassifier` for **Intent Classification**.

According to RASA’s documentation, `EmbeddingIntentClassifier` requires **dense_features** and/or **sparse_features**.

In my NLU pipeline, I have `CountVectorsFeaturizer` and `RegexFeaturizer` and they both creates **sparse_features**.

I want to know which one of these two components' output: `CountVectorsFeaturizer` and `RegexFeaturizer` is used as an input for `EmbeddingIntentClassifier`?

What’s the role of each **sparse_features**?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

All the featurizers that you put in your NLU pipeline are used as input features. So both `CountVectorsFeaturizer` and `RegexFeaturizer` are used. Sparse or dense define the way the outputs are represented in the code. We use sparse matrices where possible to save memory.
Here is the video explaining how DIET is working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWStcJDuOUk&list=PL75e0qA87dlG-za8eLI6t0_Pbxafk-cxb&index=2